# sprintf with elipses in C for macro definition results in compilation error

Tags: c, printf

I am defining a macro to print some debug over UART but I am running into a problem. The compiler does not like my use of an elipses in the sprintf statement:

```
#define LOG_INFO(_str, ...)  { char * _buf[384] = {0}; sprintf(*_buf, _str, ...); UART2_Write((void*)_buf[0], sizeof(_buf)); }
```

Results in...

```
../src/config/default/log_util.h:40:77: error: expected expression before '...' token
```

Indicating its use in the sprintf statement. I don't know if I am uning it incorrectly or if this is a compiler limitation, although the compiler (XC32) is said to handle this sort of thing.

Any corrections to the code or suggestions for a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, showing what you tried to solve the issue.  Did you look up the preprocessor's manual how to use variadics?

Comment: `char * _buf[384];` is an array of 384 pointers to `char`. To have a buffer of 384 characters remove the asterisk and use `char _buf[384];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your macro:

- you cannot use `...` to expand the macro variable argument list. Use `__VA_ARGS__` for that.
- include the format string to cover the case where the argument list is empty.
- define `_buf` as a regular `char` array, not an array of pointers.
- `use` snprintf` to prevent buffer overflows
- pass `strlen(_buf)` to `UART2_Write()`, not the full array size.
- wrap the code inside a `do` / `while` loop so `LOG_INFO("hello");` expands to a single statement.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define LOG_INFO(...)  do { char _buf[384]; snprintf(_buf, sizeof _buf, __VA_ARGS__); \ 
                            UART2_Write((void *)_buf, strlen(_buf)); } while (0)
```

Note that there is no need to define this as a macro. You could use a function instead:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int LOG_INFO(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    char buf[384];
    size_t len = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (len > sizeof(buf) - 1)
        len = sizeof(buf) - 1;
    UART2_Write((void *)buf, len);
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The reason I liked the idea of using a macro was because I could define several log levels and define uart print functions accordingly, ie. '#if LOG_LEVEL_INFO
#define LOG_INFO(...)  do stuff
#else
#define LOG_INFO(...) //do nothing
#endif'

Comment: @TristanRitchie: even with a function, you can still use a macro to by-pass the function call: `#if LOG_LEVEL_INFO == 0 #define LOG_INFO(...) /* do nothing */ #endif` and disable the macro in the function definition: `int (LOG_INFO)(const char *format, ...) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Replace ... with `__VA_ARGS__` in the body of the macro